# Set bulk size using an arithmetic expression instead of a ternary expression

Tags: language-agnostic, refactoring

In the following snippet (hardcoded values are just an example):

```
int nBulk = 30,      // bulk size
    nMax = 130;      // max records to retrieve
    nRetrieved = 0;  // records retrieved so far
do
{
   var response = GetRecords(nBulk);
   nRetrieved += response.Count;
   nBulk = nMax - nRetrieved >= nBulk ? nBulk : nMax - nRetrieved;
}
while (nRetrieved < response.Total && nRetrieved < nMax);
```

`nBulk` is assigned with a new value using a ternary expression.

Can the ternary expression be replaced with a simple arithmetic expression (i.e., no branches)?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing indicates that `nMax==response.Total`: consequently I deduce that last `GetRecords` request is going to return an effectively `nRetrieved <= nRequested`.

If `GetRecords` has this capacity to read just enough available, there is no necessity to modify `nBulk` inside the loop from the code you are showing.

However, if I would see such code, my deduction would be that modifying `nBulk` for the last read might be necessary because `GetRecords` has a side effect - like filling a buffer - IOW, that a protection is absolutely necessary in order to avoid a buffer overflow.

In this case, the branch would be the least of the problems: having a method/function modifying states, but requiring the knowledge of the internal buffer limitation (`nMax`) at sender/caller site is dangerous!

This is why I would tend to move the protection wrt. `nMax` inside the `GetRecords` method/function rather than outside, and if you do so, the problem is resolved at send site: no need to modify `nBulk` in the loop anymore, and no need to devise about `nMax`.

Of course, the test will be moved inside `GetRecords` and thus won't disappear. But frankly, why is it going to be a problem? Couldn't you increment the bulkSize so that this test becomes absolutely neglectable?

If you cannot for whatever reason, then:

1. Do a first read to get the Total remaining size to read
2. handle the case when nRemaining >= nMax by truncating to nMax outside the loop
3. loop while nRemaining >= nBulk, and decrement nRemaining by effectively nRetrieved
4. perform a last GetRecords with nRemaining request.

There is still a test in the loop (nRemaining >= nBulk), so all this seems pretty useless.

To avoid this test, you must be sure that the effectively `nRetrieved` is equal to the requested `nBulk` when there is enough to get (nothing indicates that in your code).

In this case, you can then perform a division at step 3. `nLoop=integer_floor_division(Total/nBulk)`, perform this number of loop (and have some compiler do the loop unrolling for you in order to reduce the number of tests on average), then perform the GetRecords for the remaining (modulo/remainder) `Total%nBulk` at step 4.

All you will get IMO is a code more fragile and brittle, with a risk of annihilating the marginal gains by populating the code cache... The question you should ask is: do I really need this micro-optimization and why?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **Yes**, but it's pretty ugly:

```
nBulk = (nBulk + (nMax - nRetrieved) + Math.Abs(nBulk - (nMax - nRetrieved)))/2;
```

If you want to avoid `Abs` then you could do it this way:

```
nBulk = (nBulk + (nMax - nRetrieved) 
      + Math.Sqrt((nBulk - (nMax - nRetrieved)) * (nBulk - (nMax - nRetrieved))))/2;
```

which is probably worse.

Long story short, there's no good "Language Agnostic" way to do this because there's no Lanugae Agnostic way to convert from booleans to integers without branching.  In those languages where you cna just say:

```
int i = (true);
```

then it's a different story.